# characterization of potential

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

So i have a force field $F(x,y)$ and i have to find out wether it is a potential or not.

My first idea was to calculate : $dU=Fdr$ (where $r$ is the radius vector) , to integrate on both sides and hence to see if $U$ is path dependent or not. That turned out to be right.

I was thinking about another approach: we know that , if a potential exists then $F=-\nabla U$
So if $F$ is a potential it must be possible to find such a $U$ , wich in my case wasn't possible, hence $F$ is not a potential.

My question:

(1) Is the second approach right?

(2) are there othere ways for solving this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If a force which can be derived from a potential energy function then it is called **conservative**, not potential. Potentials and forces are separate concepts.

Comment: This is a math problem as stated, so shouldn't really be on this site. Try math SE, that being said, consider differentiation of the components of F. If it has a potential one should have $\frac{\partial F_x}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial F_y}{\partial x}$. If this holds, a potential exists. Think about it.

Comment: @michaelbrown I believe the OP meant to say conservative and is asking how to know when this is the case.

Comment: @Will I know. I was just correcting the terminology.

Comment: @michaelbrown good work.

Comment: @Will  now i remeber , yes that's a nice way. I would like to know if my second approach is right too. So If i can find a potential $U$ sich that $F=-\nabla U$ then the force can be derived from a potential energy function otherwise not?

Comment: @MichaelBrown I was confused too about the terminology. This is a problem from irodov's book. There are given two fields $F(x,y)$ and it is asking : Find out whether this fields are potential. Could you clarify the problem with the terminology a bit?

Comment: Well how are you looking for the potential? How do you know there isn't one? The best way is to do what I said, then you know if one exists...

Comment: @Will I would find it by integrating $\nabla U$ , knowing $F$. But in my special case i came to a contradiction in the first constant of integration $C(y)$. Well i was just courious about knowing different approaches so to understand the topic better , thanks for the hint $\frac{\partial F_x}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial F_y}{\partial x}$

Comment: Yes, if you integrate $F\cdot dr$ along different paths with the same end points and get different results you can be sure that the force is **non-conservative** (or you have made a mistake :)) and therefore a potential doesn't exist. But in most cases, using my hint is much faster. Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is possible: if you can prove that there cannot exist a function $U$ such that $F=-\nabla U$, then the force field $F$ cannot be conservative.

The problem is that doing that directly is usually hard, because you have to find an argument that will prove that for **all** functions $U$, the gradient $-\nabla U$ does not equal $F$. Thus we usually find more subtle ways to deal with this; your path integration scheme is one example. The simplest one is probably the vector calculus scheme mentioned in the comments: we know that for all scalar functions $U$ the identity $\nabla\times\nabla U=0$ holds, so that therefore if $\nabla \times F$ is nonzero or not defined, even at a single point, then $F$ cannot equal any $\nabla U$.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I posted my specific problem and the attempt to proof that such a $U$ does not exist here:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/445055/characterization-of-potential , it would be great if you could take a look and give me feedback.